# Transformation of data cassandra under SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, cassandra, etl, nosql

I have a relational database created under SQL server and I want to transform it via SSIS to a Cassandra database.
Then I installed the Cassandra ODBC connection driver and I configured the connection and message and successfully displayed and after I installed the destination Cassandra source component under SSIS.
I created my project and I configure the connection but the problem is that I always have this error message display on my screen that I did not understand.

> The zero-based index must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the argument list size

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a table from the Cassandra Database to perform some operation using SSIS. 
"Use a table" should list all the tables connected with the database you must have mentioned while configuring a connection.